# Where clause in LINQ query using a function

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of code:

```
IList<Opportunity> filteredOpportunityProperties = new List<Opportunity>();
List<LookupWithIntId> selectedProperties = opportunityFilter.PropertyTypes;
List<string> propertyTypes = selectedProperties.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();

opportunities.Where((item) =>
    {
        string productType = item.Properties[0].ProductType;
        bool propertyMatch = propertyTypes.Any(propTypes => productType.Contains(propTypes));
        if (propertyMatch) select item;
    });
```

if the condition matches I want that item to be selected. However, I get the error:

> Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Any suggestions!

Comment: wow this is crazy! i didnt know you can do this with linq!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your where clause, change this line:

```
if(propertyMatch) select item;
```

To this:

```
return propertyMatch;
```

The where clause will return the item if the predicate result is true, so you just need to return the boolean result.